# how to deploy docker image in gcp vm

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to deploy a simple R Shiny app containerized in a Docker image, onto a virtual machine hosted by Google Cloud Platform, but I'm having problems.

The files are stored on a Github [repo](https://github.com/hughandersen/linear) and the Docker image is built using a trigger on GCP/[Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/run-builds-on-github) Build. The Docker file is based on the [rocker](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny/%7E/dockerfile/)/shiny format.

The build is triggered correctly and starts to build, but the build keeps timing out after 10min.

```
TIMEOUT ERROR: context deadline exceeded
```

Is there a command I can add to the Dockerfile to extend the build time, or is my Dockerfile wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend the timeout with a Cloud Build config (cloudbuild.yaml).  The default timeout for a build is 10 minutes.  Note that you define timeouts for each step as well as the entire build: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config

For your app, the cloudbuild.yaml would look something like

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker' 
  args: ['build', '--tag=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/linear', '.'] # build from Dockerfile
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/linear'] # push tagged images to Container Registry
timeout: '1200s' # extend timeout for build to 20 minutes
```